# How to password protect a page with Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to set up some page in Laravel that require a password to view.

A page is a model, called Page.

Each page has an associated password, stored in the Pages database table.

The schema

```
Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('client_id');
    $table->string('url');
    $table->text('content');
    $table->string('password');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I have a route, e.g. `Route::get('/page/{url}', 'PageController@index')->middleware('gate');` which will show the 'page', it's just a blade/vue file with specific information injected into the template.
These pages allow the user to upload files via AJAX.

Currently, I created some middleware to actual authentication part.

**Middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Cookie::get($request->route('url'))){
        return $next($request);
    }
    session(['page' => $request->route('url')]);
    return redirect()->route('gate',['page'=> $request->route('url')]);
}
```

**PublicController.php**

```
public function gate_check(Request $request)
{
  //this part just ensures the correct page is loaded after being authed
  $past = parse_url($request->session()->get('_previous')['url']);

  if(array_key_exists('query', $past)){
    $page = str_replace('page=', '',parse_url($request->session()->get('_previous')['url'])['query']);

    $stored_password = Page::where('url', $page)->first()->password;
    $password = $request->password;  

    if($password === $stored_password){
      //if password matches, then redirect to that page
      return redirect()->route('page', session('page'));
    } else {
      //else redirect them back to the login page to try again
      return back();
    }
  } else {
    //if there is no page information that use should go to, just send them to google instead
    return redirect('https://google.com');
  }

}
```

The idea of the middleware/auth method was to redirect the user to a login page if they weren't authed. **This login page consists only of a password that you need to enter.**

Once they enter it, I set a cookie so that they can bypass having to re-login again.

**I now realise that is is insecure, or at least it seems that way as the expiry time of the cookie can be manipulated by the client/user - resulting in them being able to stay logged in forever.**

Just wish to re-iterate that the method described above is working, but it is insecure. I also should re-iterate that these 'pages' allow users to upload files via ajax. And only should the user be allowed to upload if they're on that specific page e.g. by CSRF.

I need a **secure** way to password protect pages, which the expiry time of the 'session' can be customised. I'd also need a way to 'refresh' or 'extend' the active session without a page refresh using AJAX so that the user can stay on the upload page (in case uploads take a long time).

**Standard user account with username/email & password is not applicable. Password only.**

Wordpress has this feature built in - why is it so hard to do with Laravel for what seems so trivial?

How would you approach this?

Comment: send the password as a request parameter you stored for the user. then you could validate the password in the middleware.

Comment: And what would that achieve?

Comment: page is loaded, form for the page access is displayed. On the form post request you call the middleware, validate the password - redirect or allow

Comment: The problem isn't exactly the middleware, what I wrote in my post is working in terms of authentication. The problem is specifically the fact that the cookie can be manipulated _after_ the user has logged in. I don't want them to have to enter the password every time they try to access the page. It also needs to protect against unauthorised AJAX requests

Comment: okay then. How about adding a row for users table, which will store a session token that will be used as a validation for the user session.

Comment: Because user accounts aren't something that is required/wanted. My goal is to just allow users to enter only a password, as the link to the page will be given to random people. Should just work for anyone who has the link and the password

Comment: How about adding a table with cookies and expire date of it? Then add a validation in your handle function.

Comment: One suggestion:   Storing passwords as plain-text in your database is not a good idea. Store hashed password in your database and whenever the user passes in a password compare its hash to stored hash in your database. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/hashing

Comment: @SapneshNaik Yes, fully aware of this but it's how it has to be for certain reasons

Comment: You could store a cache item with the same expiry as the cookie, check for the cache item in the middleware (as well as cookie) and if it doesn't exist, redirect to the password input form?

Comment: @stokoe0990 as stated both in the question and bounty text: `I'd also need a way to 'refresh' or 'extend' the active session without a page refresh using AJAX so that the user can stay on the upload page`

Comment: Using a cache item you could definitely add an "extension" to the timer. You could probably do away with the cookie entirely and handle it all in your application's cache. Not sure how that'd affect performance, mind.

Comment: where do you facing the problem in authentication or customise the session?

Comment: Your bounty seems to request us to build the code for you; SO is NOT a code-building platform, we will help you answer your questions and guide you to the implementation. We are here to help, not work for you.

Comment: @milo526 The bounty **explicitly** asks for code examples and that is not the same as building it for me. I've also provided my own WIP implementation, which could be modified slightly to find a more optimal solution. However, your comments suggest nothing is provided and I'm here expecting a fully written app. You are just categorically incorrect. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I would have done:

> Standard user account with username/email & password is not
>   applicable. Password only.

For non standard user account, you may yourself generate a guest id on every correct password entered and store it to session.

```
Schema::create('active_guests', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->bigIncrements('guest_id'); # on your model specify this as primary key
$table->unsignedBigInteger('page_id'); # authorized for after validating password
$table->integer('expires_at'); # store it as unixtimestamp now()->addHours(5)->timestamp
$table->timestamps();
});
```

You can just query this way to check authentication

```
$page = Page::where('url', $page)->where('password', $password)->first();
if ($page) {
ActiveGuest::updateOrcreate(....);
Session::get('pages_authorized_for', [array_of_pages]);
// push the new page id and store it back to session as array
} else {
// incorrect password or page removed
}
```

> Just wish to re-iterate that the method described above is working,
>   but it is insecure. I also should re-iterate that these 'pages' allow
>   users to upload files via ajax. And only should the user be allowed to
>   upload if they're on that specific page e.g. by CSRF.
>
> I need a secure way to password protect pages, which the expiry time
>   of the 'session' can be customised. I'd also need a way to 'refresh'
>   or 'extend' the active session without a page refresh using AJAX so
>   that the user can stay on the upload page (in case uploads take a long
>   time).

From your ajax you can just increment the expiry time on `active_guests` table.

For longer upload time to be extended you may add a `last_activity` as timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Writing your own authentication solution is hard. Is it possible to reconsider the strategy for securing the pages?

If you able to follow the normal user based authentication strategy then you could utilise the authentication services which Laravel provides and it may also provide other advantages by removing edge cases you may encounter.

Depending on the number of pages you have to authenticate, a boolean column for each page could be added to the User table or you could add a "pages" column of type sting which holds a list of pages this user has access to.

The Laravel Authorization Policies (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#creating-policies) can then be used to enforce access to the page and within Blade you can use the policy to build the dynamic list of pages available to the user (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#via-blade-templates)

Other benefits:
- Avoids sharing a common password for each page. You may not know if the password has been shared outside of the authorised group of users and changing it will impact all users of the page.

- If a user forgets a password then they can utilise the standard Password Reset process.
- User does not need to track multiple passwords if they have access to multiple pages and Password managers struggle when there are multiple passwords for a domain.
- Knowing which pages a user has access to can assist usability by providing a homepage that lists all the pages available to the specific user.

Comment: It's not possible to reconsider the strategy, it's just supposed to be a disposable password, no user accounts. It being shared around isn't a massive concern as there are other security procedures in place surrounded the site as a whole.

Comment: If sharing of the password is not a massive concern, could you achieve what is needed by just hosting each page on a path that cannot be guessed/easily brut-forced. eg example.com/640bec04-5fa8-43a0-8881-dedcd1be32a8? Ensure directory listings are disabled on the web server.

Comment: Unfortunately not @balmainRob

Answer (score 2):

Use session instead of cookies. Changes for **Middleware**:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{   

    if(in_array($request->route('url'), session('pages',[]))){
       return $next($request);
    }

    session(["current-page"=>$request->route('url')]);
    return redirect()->route('gate');
}
```

Changes for **Controller**:

```
public function gate_check(Request $request)
{
    if(session()->has("current-page")){

        $stored_password = Page::where('url', session("current-page"))
           ->first()->password;

        if($request->password === $stored_password){
            $pages = session("pages",[]);
            array_push($pages, session("current-page"));
            session(["pages"=> $pages]);
            //if password matches, then redirect to that page
            return redirect()->route('page', ["url" => session("current-page")]);
        } else {
            //else redirect them back to the login page to try again
            return back();
        }
    } else {
        //if there is no page information that use should go to, just send them 
        // to google instead
        return redirect('https://google.com');
    }
}
```

You can use hashed password to save in the database using MD5 or SHA256 or SHA512 algorithm.
For more about session , study the Laravel session documentation [click here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/session)

You can configure **session.php**, location: **root folder/config/session.php**. Such as when user close the browser then destroyed the session.

```
'expire_on_close' => true
```

Comment: Maybe advising MD5 as a hashing algorithm for security purposes isn't the best idea; MD5 collision have become readily available, better use something like bcrypt for which laravel has built-in support.  Having said that, hashing the algorithm is a very good suggestion over plain-text storage.

Comment: The reason passwords are plain text are because they need to be visible. I will however add some reversable-encryption with a key that is no stored in the database so that will at least provide some type of cover. In regards to this answer, it's great that you used my base code and I'll give this ago and come back to you